# My character is not moving forward in 2d unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private Rigidbody2D _myRigidbody;
public float speed;
void Start () {
    _myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update () {
    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    _myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, _myRigidbody.velocity.y);
}
}
```

I set speed as 7 in inspector. When I start it in Unity, the character doesn't move but the animation works. What should I do to fix it? (Unity 5) Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `move`? are you sure it's not 0? `0 * 0 = 0`

Comment: in the tutorial which I watched, assigning the value for move was just like; `float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` and it worked for him. And as its my first trying I just wanted to write same codes. Is that about Unity versions? @DLeh

Comment: Try checking the Input settings for your project. Normally there is an entry for "Horizontal" axis but maybe somehow it's missing in yours?

Comment: @Agumander yes there is an entry for it, with defaults.

Comment: Does the character have a Rigidbody2D attached?

Comment: yes it does :) @Agumander

Comment: Just checking :) I tried the code you posted and it did indeed move the character, so it's strange that it doesn't work for you. Try using Debug.Log() on the "move" variable to print its value to the console.

Comment: `0
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Player:Update() (at Assets/Player.cs:16)`
so the problem is that, move=0, how do I fix this ? @Agumander

Comment: Are you using WASD or the Arrow Buttons?

Comment: @Aizen Neither, I just want it to start moving when it starts

Comment: This is what you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOciDnH5z-8&list=PLP65kMiSljItth6MkoCEZByJfNpiBv7Ol&index=6

Comment: Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); gets the input from the keyboard or gamepad inputs. If you don't press anything this stays at zero. If you want the object to just move on its own, you should try just setting move to a number instead of using Input.GetAxis

Comment: I solved the problem, @Agumander yes I tried to use arrow buttons with my code and it didn't work too.. It's because I tried the application in "maximize" mode and it's because i couln't see the whole layout without it. After i changed the main camera option, problem fixed :) Finally it works..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are creating a reference to an empty object,

```
_myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

this line says that _myRigidbody = myRigidBody; wich is a null.

try:

```
_myRigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```